# from hubspot.connection import APIKey working in Python2 but gives error in Python 3 ImportError: No module named hubspot.connection

Tags: python

I want to create contacts in hubspot using python.
In Python2 the import is successful but in Python3 it gives error

```
>>> from hubspot.connection import APIKey
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named hubspot.connection
>>>
```